# autocomplete.js not working properly and not populating other fields

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to get email and phone via name. Name is coming but upon selection the email and phone fields do not populate and in console I see error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelectedItemData' of undefined
    at S.fn.init.a.fn.getSelectedItemData (jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js:10)
    at Object.onSelectItemEvent (add-invoice.php:276)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js:10)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.v.handle (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.each (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.trigger (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
```

And my code is:

```
<script>
var mgrOptions = {
    url: function(phrase) {
        return "dirSearch.php?t=mgr&phrase=" + phrase;
    },
    getValue: "name",
    list: {
        onSelectItemEvent: function() {
            var email = $("#txtCaseName").getSelectedItemData().email;
            var phone = $("#txtCaseName").getSelectedItemData().phone;

            $("#txtCaseEmail").val(email).trigger("change");
            $("#txtCasePhone").val(phone).trigger("change");
        }
    }
};

$("#txtCaseName").easyAutocomplete(mgrOptions);
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong ???

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the necessary files downloaded and added in:

```html
<!-- JS file -->
<script src="/easyAutocomplete/jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js"></script>
    
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/easyAutocomplete/easy-autocomplete.min.css">
    
<!-- Additional CSS Themes file - not required-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/easyAutocomplete/easy-autocomplete.themes.min.css">
    
<!-- Using jQuery with a CDN -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

If you still aren't getting anything once the files have been referenced, inspect the page...in Chrome got to Network and then select Fetch/XHR in the filter line.  Start typing in the form field values that you would expect to return something and it should show the struct that your php script is returning.  Make sure that is working also.